# PHP GD - distort image to Mercator Projection view

Tags: php, 3d, textures, projection, mercator

i have an image that rendered from data i have on my DB.
i need to convert this image, with [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) method, to distorted image that when i'll wrap a 3d sphere with it it'll looks realistic.

do anyone know what are the formulas i need to use to make the distorted image?

i'm using PHP with GD.

thanks.

Comment: This is going to be tough and very slow using PHP and GD. You may want to expand your search beyond PHP. Can you use and install third party tools on your server?

Comment: acctually i also have Imagick on my server but i hate to use PHP with it since the PHP's API is very poor vs. the GD's one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to use normal graphics techniques to wrap this around a sphere I don't think you strictly want to use Mercator projection as that doesn't work at the poles.

The normal 3D texture mapping for spheres is simply a 2:1 aspect ratio bitmap, where the X axis maps directly to `[0, 360)` degrees of longitude and the Y axis to `[-90, +90]` degrees of latitude.

So just take your lat/long values from your database and scale them *linearly* to pixel coordinates, e.g. (assuming [0, 0] is at top left and [w, h] is the size of the bitmap):

```
x = (longitude + 180) * w
y = (90 - latitude) * h
```

**EDIT** - I misread the question and didn't realise you *already* have an image.  If AIUI that original image is the one that's in Mercator projection, then your problem is simply to undo the non-linear scaling of that image's vertical axis.  The horizontal axis can remain unchanged because Mercator uses a linear scale for longitude.

Comment: yes, my image already draw based on the 1:2 ratio: (-180) to 180 longitudes and 90 to (-90) latitude. but now i need to take the whole image and scale it on the right places follow by the Mercator Projection method.

Comment: Why do you need mercator?  The linearly-scaled spherical projection you apparently already have is _the_ most common texture format for wrapping around a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is georefrenced, then maybe this should be moved to https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

YOu could look at GDAL, the free+opensource Geospatial Data Abstraction Library, for this kind of reprojection. There is a PHP binding available, called PHP mapscript. I think there is little documentation available, though.

In order to use PHP mapscript, you'd also have to also set up a UMN mapserver (running as a cgi script of a webserver) and let it do the reprojection. YOu need to do a lot of work to set up and configure it and then push it to its limits to fit your needs.

Comment: "georeferenced" means it has -or could have- some spatial context (you could give it spatial coordinates (like latitude and longitude). Is it a map that you want to mercator-project?